# Cakephp 1.3 JsHelper for AjaxHelper

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp, helper, cakephp-1.3

I'm start using cakephp and i made a demo app using `AjaxHelper`

`$ajax->link('title', 'url', array('update' => 'mydiv'))`

Now i want to migrate that to cakephp 1.3 and AjaxHelper is deprecated on cake 1.3 and will be removed, so i want to accomplish the same with `JsHelper` which is replacing the functionality of `AjaxHelper` and `JavascriptHelper` I just can't find how to do that.

I want to upgrade the versions to use jQuery out of the box with cakephp 1.3 and get rid of Prototype javascript library.
so, any help ?

I've already read the migration guide and nothing found yet.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see anything in the 1.3 api about the ajax helper being deprecated. http://api13.cakephp.org/class/ajax-helper If anything I would start here, http://api13.cakephp.org/class/js-helper#method-JsHelperlink

Answer (score 1):

Use `$js->link('title', 'url', array('update'=>'mydiv'))`
Don't forget to `$js->writeBuffer()` in the view.
Take a look at manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1593/Methods).

Comment: thanks, that was what i tried before but wasn't working because of i had prototype still included, it seems one interfere with the other. Now fully working after remove prototype, AjaxHelper and JavascriptHelper